# No template named 'unary_function' in namespace 'std'; did you mean '__unary_function'?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, xcode15

Just upgraded my Xcode to 15.0, and suddenly it started giving me the following error in RCT_Folly

`No template named 'unary_function' in namespace 'std'; did you mean '__unary_function'?`

this is the line where it fails:

> struct hash_base : std::unary_function<T, std::size_t> {};

I tried removing cached data and derived data & cleaning build. Tried removing pods and node_modules as well. But nothing has helped.

Comment: React Native and boost have now fixed there source. Boost use BOOST_NO_CXX98_FUNCTION_BASE to block using these deprecated functions. Unfortunately by default boost tries to guess if your compile has them rather than turning them off in c++17 and above as it should.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

[image]

In my case, I followed Xcode's suggestion after the build failed. I simply clicked on 'Fix,' and everything is working fine now.

I hope it will be fixed in the next updates.

Comment: Somehow, my Xcode gets stuck when I press the fix button. The build or run menu doesn't work afterward. I have to force-kill Xcode, and once I start it again, it shows the same error.

Comment: update std::unary_function to std::__unary_function

Answer (score 46):

Until this is fixed in the source files, the best option is to add the removed libcpp function in your podfile, as solved here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/37748#issuecomment-1580589448

```
  post_install do |installer|
      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= ['$(inherited)', '_LIBCPP_ENABLE_CXX17_REMOVED_UNARY_BINARY_FUNCTION']
        end
      end
  end
```

Answer (score 43):

I got this error in my terminal after running `npx react-native run-ios`. I resolved it with the following steps:

1. Open Xcode
2. Click on the play icon to launch the simulator
3. The simulator will fail, but Xcode will show you the error in the sidebar. Click on the error to see where the error is in the code.
4. Click on the button "Fix"
5. Done! Now the simulator will run successfully.

[image]

Comment: My Xcode gets stuck when I press the fix button. The build or run menu doesn't work afterward. I have to force-kill Xcode, and once I start it again, it shows the same error.

Comment: @MiteshBaraiya It looks like you manually edited the line of code in Xcode (per the answer you posted below). This is probably why clicking "Fix" does not work in your case?

Comment: No, it only happens when I press the fix button. I didn't understand what the issue was, but I had to push and reclone the project to fix the problem.

Answer (score 16):

It's somehow silly but I resolved it by putting `__unary_function` as XCode is suggesting.

So the actually line would be..

> struct hash_base : std::__unary_function<T, std::size_t> {};

Comment: Yeah I'm getting this too now - this "fix" works, I wonder if it's going to be rolled into something official for RN...

Comment: Agreed @MattRoberts, We keep getting new silly errors with each Xcode update.

Comment: @MiteshBaraiya This is not a "silly error". It was [deprecated in C++11 and removed in C++17](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/unary_function). I guess Clang has just caught up to C++17.

Comment: same issue. I have changed it and now it working. but does it has some effects on other code.

Comment: Right @JamalUdDin, I was thinking the same because we would be using the removed function in code. But I guess using it is the only way until they fix officially in RN

Comment: I just wanted to know that is this change gonna break something? I mean this will not lead to any crash?

Comment: update your Podfile otherwise it cause app to be crash in react-native-maps if you just fix this
follow @ash answer

Comment: @JeremyP I'd say it is silly error, as most on clang compared to gcc. The latter is less strict and gives devs less pain.

Comment: @old-ufo It's a function that has been deprecated for more than ten years and was removed from the standard six years ago. If you've still got it in your code, you deserve all you get. If you are maintaining a library and it is still using a function that was deprecated twelve years ago, you need to seriously think about your priotrities and everybody else should be questioning their use of your library.

Comment: @JeremyP Amazing how you are quick to jump to conclusion. 
I'll give you an example. Here is library https://github.com/cvg/limap/ - NEW computer vision algorithm, presented at CVPR2023. Research code, freshly written. Was perfectly working on Linux and MacOS before Xcode 15 update. 
Was reusing LATEST version of Boost available with `brew install`. 
So, I shouldn't use Boost? Or Boost (one of the most popular C++ dev tools) authors have to think about their priorities?

Comment: @old-ufo Don't blame Clang for implementing C++17 (six years old) blame the maintainers of the libraries for ignoring twelve years of deprecation warnings. There's no excuse.

Answer (score 12):

all library must update their code to use std::function & std::bind instead of unary_function

Workaround

Select Pods > Build Settings >
In section Apple Clang - Preprocessing > under Macro section

[image: preview add line]

add in release & debug -> _LIBCPP_ENABLE_CXX17_REMOVED_UNARY_BINARY_FUNCTION

ps : to add this just clic on the column then clic on "+" at the bottom -> then paste : _LIBCPP_ENABLE_CXX17_REMOVED_UNARY_BINARY_FUNCTION
[image: preview add line]

Comment: I tried it earlier with a reference from GitHub, but unfortunately, it didn't work for me. I hope it will work for someone else

Comment: still have the issue ? wanna share to me ? @MiteshBaraiya

Comment: I resolved it by replacing 'unary_function' with '__unary_function'. @tetar

Answer (score 5):

> @Ash is Right  I update my Xcode and iOS version to 17.0  Everything
> was working fine, but when I ran it on iOS 17, I got this error.

```
No template named 'unary_function' in namespace 'std'; did you mean '__unary_function'
```

> I followed the steps provided to fix it, and the app started running.
> However, it crashed when I opened the map screen, which was using
> react-native-maps. After that, I deleted the pod, reinstalled the node
> modules, but the same issue persisted. What's surprising is that when
> I added the following code to my Podfile and reinstalled the pod, the
> app started working properly and fine.
> you have to fix both.

```
 post_install do |installer|
      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= ['$(inherited)', '_LIBCPP_ENABLE_CXX17_REMOVED_UNARY_BINARY_FUNCTION']
        end
      end
  end
```

Answer (score 4):

You have two options if you can control the compilation flags,

1. Make clang reenable the deprecated functions: `-D_LIBCPP_ENABLE_CXX17_REMOVED_UNARY_BINARY_FUNCTION`
2. Prevent Boost from using the deprecated function:  `-DBOOST_NO_CXX98_FUNCTION_BASE`

Answer (score 2):

For any React Native users encountering this error, Facebook have released a fix in v0.72.5 - [release notes](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.72.5).

> XCode 15 fixes (21763e85e3, 0dbd621c59 & 8a5b2d6735)

`npm update react-native`

Comment: Still getting this same error even after updating my project... :-(

Answer (score 1):

In case you still have an older RN version,

This worked for me:

```
post_install do |installer|
        react_native_post_install(installer)
        __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
        
        installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
            installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
                if target.respond_to?(:product_type) and target.product_type == "com.apple.product-type.bundle"
                    config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
                end
            end
    
            # Set the preprocessing macro for the whole Pods project
            existing_flags = config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= ['$(inherited)']
            existing_flags << '_LIBCPP_ENABLE_CXX17_REMOVED_UNARY_BINARY_FUNCTION'
            config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] = existing_flags
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be another workaround for this

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/37748#issuecomment-1580334650

Comment: Please add details to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i '' 's/std::unary_function/__unary_function/g' ios/Pods/boost/boost/container_hash/hash.hpp
```

fix with grep