# React Native Xcode Archive IPA generation not working

Tags: javascript, xcode, react-native, ipa, xcode-archive

After upgrading to Xcode 15, my react native project failed to build the IPA. But it's working fine while I run it via simulator.

I am getting the following error:

> Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
>
> PhaseScriptExecution Bundle\ React\ Native\ code\ and\ images
>
> Failed to construct transformer: Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:68:19) at Object.createHash (node:crypto:138:10)

When I try to build the IPA using Xcode Archive, I get the following error:

> Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Comment: What is your node version?

Comment: Might be [related to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77142428/9026710)